# Responsive div columns where column items get shifted on screen resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid, responsive

I have three columns called `<div class="pageColumnOneThird">`.

Inside each column I fetch images and posts using PHP where the newest item gets placed in the `top left column` and the next one in the `top middle column` and the third one in the `top right column` before it goes back to the `left column` again.

Now I am trying to make this responsive, so that when two columns are displayed, the placement of each image/post are changed.

**example:** When there are only two columns side-by-side I need the first row of items to be element 1 and 2. Then the second row has to be element 3 and 4.

Is there any way to do this using CSS?

If not, is there any fast jQuery code that can do this for me?

**Code**

```
<!-- FIRST COLUMN -->
<div class="pageColumnOneThird">
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 1</div>
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 4</div>
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 7</div>
</div>
<!-- SECOND COLUMN -->
<div class="pageColumnOneThird">
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 2</div>
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 5</div>
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 8</div>
</div>
<!-- THIRD COLUMN -->
<div class="pageColumnOneThird">
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 3</div>
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 6</div>
    <div class="itemWrap">Element 9</div>
</div>
```

Heres a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhxwpw6/) as well.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: So you just want to use media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries. I don't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Martin Yes, I'm using media queries to change the width of each column. However, I need the item elements to stay in order, even if there are only 2 columns side by side, or one. When you resize the window in the jsfiddle you can see that the 2 item element goes after the 7th in the first column. I need them to stay in order.

Comment: Why do you split them into columns? You could just make your itemWrap divs of the similar 30%-like width, in the inline-block mode, so they would just flow in order inside a single common parent div. On a narrower screen you would just change their width to 50% or so, and they would stay in required order, now in 2 columns.

Comment: @JustAndrei because I am creating a perfect grid display that is opening up for different heights on the item elements. I have tried this solution and in order for me to get equal margins between all elements it gives me empty space.

Comment: OK, then why do you care that much about the right order of elements? 'Cause you have different heights, after row 5 or 7 your order won't be "in order" anymore, because of accumulated difference of heights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use one wrapper, and then just use @media queries

```css
.pageColumnOneThird {
  font-size: 0;
}
.itemWrap {
  background-color: #AEAEAE;
  margin: 2px 0;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 0 1px;
  height: auto;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .itemWrap {
    width: 50%
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .itemWrap {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pageColumnOneThird">
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 1</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 2</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 3</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 4</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 5</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 6</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 7</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 8</div>
  <div class="itemWrap">Element 9</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** Based on OP comment:

> This is not what I am looking for as I need to be allowed different
>   heights on each item element, but maintain equal margin WITHOUT adding
>   empty space in the elements. Thats why I need to use three separate
>   columns. Found a picture of what I need https://prod-foundation-forum.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/part/part_image/93067/illustration.jpg

For that type of layout the best thing for you is [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: This is not what I am looking for as I need to be allowed different heights on each item element, but maintain equal margin WITHOUT adding empty space in the elements. Thats why I need to use three separate columns. Found a picture of what I need https://prod-foundation-forum.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/part/part_image/93067/illustration.jpg

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Do you know what type of grid that is called?